# Upgrading to Angular 14 breaks HttpClient and BrowserAnimationsModule

Tags: angular, angular14

I upgraded my app to angular 14, package.json here: https://pastebin.com/yMmeQShc

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
```

I get the following errors:

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' and Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

It works in Angular 13, it doesn't in Angular 14 (edited)

Comment: delete your existing node_modules folder and then run npm install